# Pass data from the main activity to another activity using intent in android studio

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-intent, parcelable

I have a problem when passing data from the main activity to another activity using `Intents`. 
I made `MainActivity`, `BaiHat class` and `SecondActivity` for getting data from the `MainActivity`.

Open logcat, there is an error like this:

> (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>           at com.myappnvt.truyendulieu.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:30))
>   **MainActivity.java:30 is line " String ten_bai_hat = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();"**

Here is the code:

```
 package com.myappnvt.truyendulieu;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class BaiHat implements Parcelable {
    private String tenBaiHat;
    private int tenFile;

    public BaiHat(String tenBaiHat, int tenFile) {
        this.tenBaiHat = tenBaiHat;
        this.tenFile = tenFile;
    }

    public BaiHat(Parcel in) {
        tenBaiHat = in.readString();
        tenFile = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<BaiHat> CREATOR = new Creator<BaiHat>() {
        @Override
        public BaiHat createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BaiHat(in);
        }

        @Override
        public BaiHat[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BaiHat[size];
        }
    };

    public String getTenBaiHat() {
        return tenBaiHat;
    }

    public void setTenBaiHat(String tenBaiHat) {
        this.tenBaiHat = tenBaiHat;
    }

    public int getTenFile() {
        return tenFile;
    }

    public void setTenFile(int tenFile) {
        this.tenFile = tenFile;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(tenBaiHat);
        dest.writeInt(tenFile);

    }
    public  static final Parcelable.Creator<BaiHat> creator = new Parcelable.Creator<BaiHat>(){
        public BaiHat createFromParcel(Parcel in){
            return new BaiHat(in);
        }
        public BaiHat[] newArray (int size){
            return  new BaiHat[size];
        }
    };
}
```

```
    package com.myappnvt.truyendulieu;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BaiHatAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<BaiHat> baiHatArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Addlist();
        adapter = new BaiHatAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.dong_bai_hat, baiHatArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String ten_bai_hat = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class)
                        .putExtra("BAIHAT", baiHatArrayList)
                .putExtra("TENBAIHAT", ten_bai_hat)
                .putExtra("POSITION",position));
            }
        });


    }
    private void Addlist(){
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewdanhsach);
        baiHatArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        baiHatArrayList.add(new BaiHat("Bến tương tư - Quang Linh", R.raw.ben_tuong_tu_quang_linh));
        baiHatArrayList.add(new BaiHat("Buồn trong kỷ niệm - Đan Nguyên", R.raw.buon_trong_ky_niem_dan_nguyen));
        baiHatArrayList.add(new BaiHat("Cát bụi cuộc đời - Phi Nhung", R.raw.cat_bui_cuoc_doi_phi_nhung));
        baiHatArrayList.add(new BaiHat("Cho vừa lòng em - Như Nguyệt", R.raw.cho_vua_long_em_nhu_nguyet));
        baiHatArrayList.add(new BaiHat("Chuyến đò không em - Tuấn Vũ", R.raw.chuyen_do_khong_em_tuan_vu));

    }
}
```

```
    package com.myappnvt.truyendulieu;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String bai_hat ="";
    int vi_tri =0;
    TextView txtlaydulieu;
    ArrayList<BaiHat> baiHatArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        txtlaydulieu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewlaydulieu);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        baiHatArrayList = (ArrayList) bundle.getParcelableArrayList("BAIHAT");
        bai_hat = baiHatArrayList.get(vi_tri).getTenBaiHat().toString();
        String songName = intent.getStringExtra("TENBAIHAT");
        txtlaydulieu.setText(songName);
        txtlaydulieu.setSelected(true);
        vi_tri = bundle.getInt("POSITION",0);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(baiHatArrayList.get(vi_tri).toString());
        MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to get item like this. instead of getting the list from the adapter you can also retrieve the source like belo. The error says nullpointer exception that means you are not getting the data from adapter.  So instead try below once.

```
String ten_bai_hat = baiHatArrayList.get(position).toString();
```

Full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BaiHatAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<BaiHat> baiHatArrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Addlist();
    adapter = new BaiHatAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.dong_bai_hat, baiHatArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String ten_bai_hat = baiHatArrayList.get(position).toString();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class)
                    .putExtra("BAIHAT", baiHatArrayList)
            .putExtra("TENBAIHAT", ten_bai_hat)
            .putExtra("POSITION",position));
        }
    });


}
private void Addlist(){
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewdanhsach);
    baiHatArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    baiHatArrayList.add(new BaiHat("Bến tương tư - Quang Linh", R.raw.ben_tuong_tu_quang_linh));
    baiHatArrayList.add(new BaiHat("Buồn trong kỷ niệm - Đan Nguyên", R.raw.buon_trong_ky_niem_dan_nguyen));
    baiHatArrayList.add(new BaiHat("Cát bụi cuộc đời - Phi Nhung", R.raw.cat_bui_cuoc_doi_phi_nhung));
    baiHatArrayList.add(new BaiHat("Cho vừa lòng em - Như Nguyệt", R.raw.cho_vua_long_em_nhu_nguyet));
    baiHatArrayList.add(new BaiHat("Chuyến đò không em - Tuấn Vũ", R.raw.chuyen_do_khong_em_tuan_vu));

}
```

}

Comment: Dear bro, many thanks for your help. I will try to edit my code follow your comment. I hope it will help.

Comment: Dear bro, I saw your code and compare to my code but I don't see the difference between them. Can you give me more details to edit my code. My problem is not solved at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement your `BaiHatAdapter` like this:

```
public class BaiHatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    public BaiHatAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int layout, int textViewId, @NonNull List<BaiHat> objects) {
        super(context, layout, textViewId, objects);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        BaiHat item = (BaiHat) super.getItem(position);
        return (item != null && item.getTenBaiHat() != null) ? item.getTenBaiHat() : "Default TenBaiHat Text";
    }
}
```

`textViewId` - id of `TextView` that will display the `ten_bai_hat` text.
Here you override the `getItem` method to return the `tenBaiHat` value. If either the item is null or the `tenBaiHat` string is null, then return some default text.

Comment: Dear bro, thank you so much for your advice. I will try to edit my code follow your comment.

Comment: Can you get me some details. I also made BaiHatAdapter. So I don't know how to edit my code follow your advice.

Comment: @nguyenvanthang I will need to see the contents of dong_bai_hat.xml. Can you edit your question and show this file?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will give you the code of BaiHatAdapter, and dong_bai_hat.xml as soon as I can. So please help me. My problem is not solved at all.